# Iterative Closest Point mapping of 3D lidar pointclouds

Tags: slam, mapping, pcl, ros-noetic, icp

I know there are several posts on ICP and I have already gone through several of those. However, I am unable to get a decent enough result in my case. This post is basically to gain in insight into ICP and I have also read that there are more recent and efficient algorithms for pointcloud registration.

**Objective**: Build a map of the environment from the pointclouds obtained from velodyne lidar.

All my codes are available [here](https://github.com/ashBabu/icp-mapping/blob/master/src/icp_mapping.cpp). The program reads from a rosbag looking for the topic `/velodyne_points` and tries to do pointcloud registration. Please find the video of incremental map building and ground truth image [here](https://github.com/ashBabu/icp-mapping/tree/master/media). After about 33 seconds into the video, the icp starts to give rubbish results.

The crux of the ICP code is as follows

```
icp.setInputSource(source_cloud);
icp.setInputTarget(target_cloud);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> aligned_cloud;
icp.align(aligned_cloud);

target_cloud = aligned_cloud.makeShared();

// Update the target cloud
*map_cloud += aligned_cloud;
```

Here the `target_cloud` and the `source_cloud` are the `i` and `i+1` pointcloud msg from the rosbag respectively. As far as I understand, the `aligned_cloud` is the `source_cloud` transformed (translated and rotated) to align with the `target_cloud` based on the computed transformation matrix during the ICP process.

Probably I have used the very basic implementation of ICP from point cloud library and the parameters of icp (`icp.set...`) have been played around too much to a point that I have run out of options.

Any pointers would be really helpful. Thanks